# Simple form in haml not rendering in another haml page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following form in rails, its in haml :

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true} do |f|
    -if @recipe.errors.any?
        #errors
            %p
                = @recipe.errors.count
                Prevented this recipe from saving
            %ul
                -@recipe.errors.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg
        .panel-body
            =f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
            =f.input :desciption, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}

        f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I am trying to render this form into another file new.html.haml :

```
%h1 New Recipe

= render 'form'

%br/

= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default"
```

but the form is not appearing, I can see the title New Recipe and the back button but no form

Any clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like everything is nested under `- if @recipe.errors.any?`. 
Try unindenting the `.panel-body` and `f.button` (which should be `= f.button`) so that they're in line with the `if`.